# Can you use a when: with a vars_prompt?

Tags: syntax, ansible

I am trying to skip the next three prompts if the user inputs y to the first prompt.

```
---

- name: User MOTD Script
  hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:

      - name: "defaultMOTD"
        prompt: "Do you want to set the MOTDs to the default? (y/n)"
        private: no

      - name: "MOTD"
        prompt: "Please input your MOTD for /etc/motd: "
        private: no
        when: defaultMOTD != "y"

      - name: "MOTDIssue"
        prompt: "Please input your MOTD for /etc/issue: "
        private: no
        when: defaultMOTD != "y"

      - name: "MOTDIssueNet"
        prompt: "Please input your MOTD for /etc/issue.net: "
        private: no
        when: defaultMOTD != "y"
```

Output when y is inputted on the first prompt.

```
Do you want to set the MOTDs to the default? (y/n): y
Please input your MOTD for /etc/motd: :
Please input your MOTD for /etc/issue: :
Please input your MOTD for /etc/issue.net: :
```

The 2nd,3rd and 4th prompts should be skipped.

Comment: Ansible is more an software provisioning, configuration management and application-deployment tool than a "language" to write programs. From the documentation I get that the intension of [Interactive input: prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) were more related to provide user passwords. Your current approach looks like you would let users provide any input, writing it unvalidated into a file for distribution and maybe later execution. Would it be possible to use templates or var files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html#ansible-builtin-pause-pause-playbook-execution), e.g.

```yaml
---

- name: User MOTD Script
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - name: "defaultMOTD"
      pause:
        prompt: "Do you want to set the MOTDs to the default? (y/n)"
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        defaultMOTD: "{{ result.user_input }}"

    - block:
        - name: "MOTD"
          pause:
            prompt: "Please input your MOTD for /etc/motd"
          register: result
        - set_fact:
            MOTD: "{{ result.user_input }}"
        - name: "MOTDIssue"
          pause:
            prompt: "Please input your MOTD for /etc/issue"
          register: result
        - set_fact:
            MOTDIssue: "{{ result.user_input }}"
        - name: "MOTDIssueNet"
          pause:
            prompt: "Please input your MOTD for /etc/issue.net"
          register: result
        - set_fact:
            MOTDIssueNet: "{{ result.user_input }}"
      when: defaultMOTD != "y"
```